# Separar Array em grupos e introduzi-los em um texto pre definido

Tags: php

Eu recebo uma string no formato:

[nome, qtd, preco, nome, qtd, preco...].

Ex: [Molho de Tomate, 12, 4.59, Pipoca, 5, 7.90...]

Desejo separar a cada 3 vírgulas um elemento e cada elemento separar em mais 3 subelementos.

Ex: `$pedido[i] = $subelemento_nome, $subelemento_qtd, $subelemento_preco;`

```
$subelemento_nome[i];
$subelemento_qtd[i];
$subelemento_preco[i];
```

E para cada elemento retornar algo como isso:

```
$pedido[i] = "<p>".$subelemento_qtd[i]."x ". $subelemento_nome[i]." - R$ ".$subelemento_preco[i]."</p><br>";
```

Retorno:

```
<p>12x Molho de Tomate - R$ 4.59</p><br>
<p>5x Pipoca - 7.90</p><br>...
```

No final de tudo enviarei a string $pedido para minha database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode remover os colchetes e separar todos os valores pela vírgula:

```
$texto = '[Molho de Tomate, 12, 4.59, Pipoca, 5, 7.90]';
$valores = explode(',', trim($texto, '[]'));
```

Assim você terá algo como:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Molho de Tomate
    [1] =>  12
    [2] =>  4.59
    [3] =>  Pipoca
    [4] =>  5
    [5] =>  7.90
)
```

Para pegar a cada três valores, utilize o [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$produtos = array_chunk($valores, 3);
```

Ficando com:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Molho de Tomate
            [1] =>  12
            [2] =>  4.59
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Pipoca
            [1] =>  5
            [2] =>  7.90
        )

)
```

Aí basta você percorrer essa lista `$produtos` e fazer o que deseja.

Por exemplo:

```
$texto = '[Molho de Tomate, 12, 4.59, Pipoca, 5, 7.90]';
$valores = explode(',', trim($texto, '[]'));
$produtos = array_chunk($valores, 3);

foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
    list($nome, $qtd, $preco) = array_map('trim', $produto);

    $preco = number_format($preco, 2, ',', '');

    echo "<p>{$qtd}x {$nome} - R$ {$preco}</p>", PHP_EOL;
}
```

A saída será:

```
<p>12x Molho de Tomate - R$ 4,59</p>
<p>5x Pipoca - R$ 7,90</p>
```

Comment: Muito bom, exatamente como eu queria. Você sabe me dizer pq echo mostra a saída como esperado mas quando vou passar pra minha database apenas o ultimo item é salvo?

Comment: O seu exemplo, por exemplo, grava na db apenas `<p>5x Pipoca - R$ 7,90</p>`

Comment: Porque deve ter feito errado :D hehehe Talvez esteja armazenando em variáveis e só salvando no banco fora do laço de repetição, aí assim salvará apenas os valores atuais das variáveis (mas é apenas especulação).

Comment: Entendi... Como eu armazeno numa variável todos resultados pra serem gravados de uma vez? Pq se eu colocar a parte do mysql no laço, é gravado individualmente cada valor.

Comment: Consegui :D, dei umas pesquisadas e encontrei a solução. Adicionei`$pedido_conteudo = "<p>{$qtd}x {$nome} - R$ {$preco}</p>\n";` e 
`$conteudo .=$pedido_conteudo;` dentro do laço, e fora do laço está a parte em mysql gravando $conteudo